# seaborn - обрезается изображение

Tags: python, графика, matplotlib, seaborn

Вывожу матрицу корреляций.
Что нужно поменять, чтобы изображение не обрезалось?

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,5))
sns.heatmap(df[features].corr(),annot = True, linewidths = 2,ax = ax)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Воспользуйтесь в конце [plt.tight_layout()](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.tight_layout.html) для того чтобы автоматически уменьшить картинку таким образом, чтобы все надписи и подписи влезали во фрейм:

```
plt.tight_layout()
```

Answer (score 0):

Либо, если у вас старая версия `matplotlib`, вручную поменяйте границы как-нибудь [так](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/issues/1773):

```
b, t = plt.ylim() # discover the values for bottom and top
b += 0.5 # Add 0.5 to the bottom
t -= 0.5 # Subtract 0.5 from the top
plt.ylim(b, t) # update the ylim(bottom, top) values
```

Либо обновите `matplotlib` до свежей версии.